# Basic Assembly Memory Location

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

Are the following the same?

```
add eax, 2
mov [eax+2], ebx
```

vs
`mov [eax+4], ebx`

am i correct to say that:
Assuming initial value stored in `eax` to be 0x40000050, both will result in writing value stored in `ebx` to address location 0x40000054? Or does `[eax+2]` and `[eax+4]` refer to different locations?

Comment: They store the value to the same location, but the first version also modifies `eax`.

Comment: Adding with add is the same as doing it in the addressing mode.  You could test that with a debugger, after pointing EAX to the start of a zeroed array in the BSS for example.